# Disabling a deadline in golang TCP

Tags: time, go, timeout

I want to set a deadline on client connection, he must do something within the first 10 seconds or else get disconnected, if he does do something, I want to remove the deadline.

```
// meConn = *TCPConn
c.meConn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second))
```

But the documentation doesn't say anything about disabling the deadline.

Also, is it safe to keep changing the deadline when a certain condition is met?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It states:

```
// SetReadDeadline sets the deadline for future Read calls.
// A zero value for t means Read will not time out.
SetReadDeadline(t time.Time) error
```

In the documentation for [SetReadDeadLine](https://golang.org/src/net/net.go)

so you will need to pass in zero when a client sends what you expect.

and the [SetDeadLine](https://golang.org/src/net/net.go) says it is setting both the reader and the writer, so make sure you also meant to set the writer.

```
   // SetDeadline sets the read and write deadlines associated
   // with the connection. It is equivalent to calling both
   // SetReadDeadline and SetWriteDeadline.
```

Comment: Yes, I want to close the connection after the deadline so I meant both. Anyways, a zero? an `int`? But that would make it error right, `int != time.Time`? I don't also recall a zero value in time. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 10):

To reset the deadline, you can call `SetDeadline` with a "zero" value as the docs stay. This the "zero" value can be set with:

```
conn.SetDeadline(time.Time{})
```